# Ruby Gem Bundle Problem - Could not find paperclip-2.3.16 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

I'm new to Ruby on Rails, and I'm setting up a dev environment following written instructions for a project. However I'm running into an issue and the error message I get barely returns any google results.

I'm on Windows 7 64 bit, Ruby 1.8.7, installed via RailsInstaller with mysql2. The issue seems to be with the Paperclip gem (I don't know what it does, or if I need it, but it's part of the project I'm joining).

I'm trying to run a rake command but I get the following (I also included the bundle install results):

```
C:\Sites\mcd-acorn>bundle install
Invalid gemspec in [C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/paperclip-2.3.16.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-07-29 00
:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/paperclip-2.3.16.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-07-29 00
:00:00.000000000Z"
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.9.2)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.9)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.5.0)
Using activemodel (3.0.9)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.3)
Using rack-mount (0.6.14)
Using rack-test (0.5.7)
Using tzinfo (0.3.29)
Using actionpack (3.0.9)
Using mime-types (1.16)
Using polyglot (0.3.2)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.2.19)
Using actionmailer (3.0.9)
Using arel (2.0.10)
Using activerecord (3.0.9)
Using activeresource (3.0.9)
Using bundler (1.0.15)
Using cancan (1.6.5)
Using highline (1.6.2)
Using net-ssh (2.1.4)
Using net-scp (1.0.4)
Using net-sftp (2.0.5)
Using net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
Using capistrano (2.8.0)
Using carmen (0.2.8)
Using cocaine (0.1.0)
Using formtastic (1.2.4)
Using haml (3.1.2)
Using mysql2 (0.2.11)
Using net-ldap (0.2.2)
Installing paperclip (2.3.16)
Using rdoc (3.9.1)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.0.9)
Using rails (3.0.9)
Using sass (3.1.7)
Using warden (1.0.5)
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem
is installed.

C:\Sites\mcd-acorn>bundle exec rake db:reset
Invalid gemspec in [C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/paperclip-2.3.16.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-07-29 00
:00:00.000000000Z"
Invalid gemspec in [C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications
/paperclip-2.3.16.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-07-29 00
:00:00.000000000Z"
Could not find paperclip-2.3.16 in any of the sources
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Ah I had something similar, and I remember it had nothing to do with the gem itself. I believe it was something to do with your version of rake, but I can't remember 100% right now. What version are you use? Running `gem list` will show you your gems installed and what version. I'll ask someone I work with about this soon to see if they remembered exactly what the issue was.

Comment: it says 0.9.2 when I do `bundle install` but when I do `gem list` it says (0.9.2, 0.8.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out updating my rubygems version to 1.8.10 solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I lost half a day on this before finally finding your solution. Sometimes the obvious is well… too obvious.

Comment: Np, I was tearing my hair out as well. In my case, I had just installed rubygems, and thought I had the most updated version to begin with. Sometimes haphazard trial and error works wonders!